# Webpack - AngularJS app not working on IE11

Tags: javascript, angularjs, internet-explorer, webpack, babel-loader

AngularJS app is using webpack, theres a few modules that was created and those were made to work with webpack as well. When running the app in all browsers everything works perfectly except on IE11. This is the current error being shown in the console of IE11.

```
SCRIPT1006: Expected ')'
File: vendor.bundle.js, Line 1, Column 546833
```

error is on one of the imported modules that has be "webpackified", tried removing the module and another one of our components which lives in a different repo errors out. Figured it might be a webpack error and that babel would resolve the issue.

.bablerc

```
{
"presets": [
    [ "env", {
     "targets": {
      "browsers": ["last 2 versions", "ie >= 11"]
    },
          "useBuiltIns": true
      }]
    ]
}
```

package.json

```
"devDependencies":{
  "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
  "babel-loader": "^7.1.4",
  "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
  "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
  "eslint": "^5.0.1",
  "eslint-loader": "^2.0.0",
  "file-loader": "^1.1.11",
  "happypack": "^5.0.0",
  "hard-source-webpack-plugin": "^0.9.0",
  "html-loader": "^0.5.5",
  "html-webpack-plugin": "^3.2.0",
  "json-loader": "^0.5.7"
},
"dependencies":{
  ...,
  "dataservice": "git+ssh://git@<remote-server>/dataService.get#webpackify",
  "cart": "git+ssh://git@<remote-server>/cart.git#webpackify"
},
"externals": [
  "dataservice/app",
  "cart/app"
]
```

using angularJS version "^1.7.2" and webpack version "^4.12.1"

inside webpack.config.js has a function to build the external modules as well as the current javascript files in the angularJS app.

webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: ["babel-polyfill", "./scripts/app.js"],
  modules.rules: [
    {  
      enforce: 'pre',
      test: /\.js$/,
      include: build_externals(),
      loader: 'eslint-loader'
    },
    {
      test: /\.js$/,
      include: build_externals(),
      use: 'happypack/loader?id=ECMAScript'
    }
  ],
  plugins: [
    {
     loader: 'babel-loader',
     options: {
      presets: ['env'],
      plugins: ['transform-es2015-modules-commonjs']
     }
   },
   new HappyPack({
    id: 'ECMAScript',
    threads: 4,
    loaders: happy_js_loader
   })
  ]
}
```

Been losing my mind with this problem. Hope someone out there will be able to help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a difference between running mode: 'development' vs. mode: 'production'? You might have better luck viewing the compiled src of vendor.bundle.js in dev because it won't be minfied.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out the solution to my problem was to give the correct path to external modules. Webpack includes these in the build process. IE works perfectly.

package.json

```
"externals": [
 "node_modules/dataservice/app",
 "node_modules/cart/app"
]
```